# Professor uploaded a recommendation meant for university 'A' to a different university 'B'

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

There are 2 universities that I was applying to for a PhD program. Lets call them 'A' and 'B'. 
The professor, who was writing a recommendation for me, uploaded the recommendation, meant for university 'A', to university 'B' and the one meant for university 'B' to university 'A'.

This error was realized by the professor after I had already submitted the entire application, so I cannot remove the recommendation from my application and request a new one.

So my queries are:

1. Can I/Should I drop a mail to the graduate program stating such as happened and request a new link(or something along those lines)?
2. If the situation is not rectified, how does that reflect onto my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How it affects you is impossible to say, not knowing nearly enough.

But it is really the professor's job to make the correction if it is needed as s/he made the error. You can send mail to the program(s) informing them of the error, of course, and they may, individually have some suggestions. But if the mail comes from the professor it would have more weight. The prof can include the proper letter in the mail, of course.

But if radically different things were said about you (unlikely) it might have an effect.

But ask your professor to provide the remedy.

Comment: I was told, by the professor, since the recommendation was strong and I am an excellent student it wont make much of a difference. The professor does not believe that its going to be a cause of concern, so action from that end is unlikely.

Comment: He is almost certainly correct in his estimation. If there is any question at the receiving institutions you can let them know of the error.

Comment: That seems a bit risky. Hypothetically, lets say the graduate programs say "It happens, here is another link re-upload it", but the professor already has told me that its not a big deal. What if he flat out refuses to re-upload it? Leaving me with a new link and no recommendation

Comment: You can't force him, of course. It isn't really an issue given his response to you. The error reflects on him, not on you. I assume the main difference between the letters is who they were addressed to. That might cause confusion (and a chuckle) but not at your expense. Relax. My first sentence of the answer was just guarding against the possibility that the letters were radically different. Presumably they weren't. If your prof thought there was an issue, he would very probably want to correct it.